# Problem displaying 'includes'

Tags: htaccess

I am having a hard time figuring this out. I hadn't changed anything on the site before this, however my webhost (BlueHost) sometimes messes with my files.

Anyway, I am not able to bring up anything on the page that is published with an include. Below is a copy of the code for the page (minus content) and a copy of my .htaccess file. I am not sure what else you need. The site is located at: https://templemountfaithful.org/ and here is the page with the code below: https://templemountfaithful.org/articles/

```
<?php $thisPage='news';?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Commentaries and News Updates from the Temple Mount Faithful</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="These articles cover the Third Temple,The Temple Mount, Jerusalem, the Jewish people, Israel, Bible prophecy, the Middle East and more.">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/style/main.css">

</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
    <?php include("/includestmf/topNavTMF-Main.inc"); ?>
</div>

<div class="colmask leftmenu">
    <div class="colleft">
        <div class="col1">
            <!-- Column 1 start -->

<!-- content -->

<h1 style="margin-bottom: .2em;">Commentaries and News Updates</h1>
<hr>
<p>
All commentaries are written by Gershon Salomon, Chairman of the Temple Mount Faithful, unless otherwise noted.</p>

<h2 class="article2">2022</h2>
<ul>

</ul>

<!--   CONTENT   -->

<!-- content //-->

<div style="font-size: .8em; color: #8f8f8f; padding-top: 10px;">
 <?php
  putenv("TZ=America/Miami");
  echo "Last modified: " . date( "F j, Y", getlastmod() );
?>
</div>

            <!-- Column 1 end -->
        </div>

        <div class="col2">
            <!-- Column 2 start -->
  <?php include("/includestmf/leftNavTMF.inc"); ?>
            <!-- Column 2 end -->
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div id="footer">
  <?php include("/includestmf/footerTMF.inc"); ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/common.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

========

```
# Last changed: April 27, 2022

AddHandler server-parsed .htm .html .inc
AddType audio/x-m4a MPEG-4 media m4a
AddType video/mp4 MPEG-4 media mp4
AddType video/x-m4v MPEG-4 media m4v

# Use PHP7 as default
Options +ExecCGI
# AddType text/html .html .htm
# AddHandler server-parsed .html .htm
AddType text/html .inc
AddHandler server-parsed .inc

# AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php
# AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm .inc

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
ServerSignature Off

ServerSignature Off

# Used for the errorpage.php file
ErrorDocument 400 /errorpage.php
ErrorDocument 401 /errorpage.php
ErrorDocument 403 /errorpage.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errorpage.php
ErrorDocument 500 /errorpage.php

SetEnv TZ America/New_York
```

Help!

Comment: "I hadn't changed anything on the site before this" - What did you change exactly? Are you implying that this used to work (as written)?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> <?php include("/includestmf/topNavTMF-Main.inc"); ?>
> ```

It looks like are trying to use a document root relative URL-path as argument to the `include` statement. This is unlikely going to work. When you include a slash prefix on the file-path, PHP looks for the file in the root of the server's filesystem. You should be using an absolute file-path here. For example:

```
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includestmf/topNavTMF-Main.inc"); ?>
```

However, you should have been seeing an E_WARNING in the PHP error log, or even on screen, alerting you to the incorrect file path?

**UPDATE:** You also have issues with your Server-Side-Includes (SSI) - they are being downloaded (eg. request `/includestmf/topNavTMF-Main.inc` in the browser). These "SSI" in fact look like PHP files as they contain "raw" (unprocessed) PHP code. I would avoid mixing SSI with PHP for this very reason. (You don't need SSI when you are using PHP.)

> ```
> AddHandler server-parsed .inc
> ```

This should be OK, however, `AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .inc` is the more usual way to activate SSI. (But staying with the `.shtml` extension is preferable to avoid conflicts.)

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteBase /
> ```

You're not using mod_rewrite in the code you've posted, so these two directives should be removed.

Comment: Thanks, but none of that really made a difference. (BTW, the includes are HTML files.)

Comment: @Lee If the includes are "HTML files" then why are you using a `.inc` extension? Why are you (trying to) parsing it for SSI? Why does it contain PHP code?

Comment: The site was built several years ago so I don't remember the reasons. I am currently in the process of changing the entire site to ".HTML". Thanks for the help!